# Why can't I copy/paste img assets from one project into new directories in second project's drawable folder?

Tags: android-studio

I downloaded a project from Github, trying to rebuild it myself for learning purposes. I'm new to Android Studio, developing on a Mac. Having trouble with what I think would be simple tasks.

The source project from Github I downloaded has several different sub directories containing image resources under the res/drawable folder. I was hoping I could just copy and paste these assets into my own project. It doesn't seem to work the way I'd expect and I don't understand what is going on.

I've tried right clicking and copy/pasting the directory I'd like to duplicate from the Github project (opened in Android Studio) into the drawable folder in my new project (Also opened in AS). Nothing seems to happen when I do this. Right clicking and selecting "reveal in finder" reveals a still unfortunately empty drawable folder.

I also tried right clicking on the specific directory I'd like to copy from the Github project and selecting "reveal in finder", thinking I'd try copying and pasting it from there into my new project. Oddly enough when I do this, the same directory isn't even the one that's opened. Instead, it opens a drawable-hdpi folder containing several assets, but it's definitely not the one I was attempting to open.

I've tried right clicking and "synchronizing" the drawable folder in my new project after copy/pasting, still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not copy android folders or directories directly into android studio. But you can copy individual files into there respective folders in your project. 
If you want to copy folders/ directories you can open the android app folder in your MAC browser and go to Application/app/src/main and paste whatever you have in the respective folders.
The main folder conrains java and res folders and an AndroidManifest.xml file. 
You can paste xml files , drawables and pngs etc in res and java classes will go into java folder.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. Would you happen to know why when I expand a folder found under drawable in Android Studio, the expanded folder appears to contain 4 images (hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi). However, when I right click on the folder and try to "Open in Finder" it on Mac, there appears to only be 1 .png image? How is this possible?

Comment: The other images are in other drawable folders like: drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi,drawable-xhdpi etc in your computer.
In android under default view you are not seeing the structure of folder-tree and folders as they are actually in Computer.
It is mainly for convenience so you can see all files easily. 
You can change the 'file showing configuration' in android by using the drop down named "android" on top of your folder tree.